# Remove the previous activity from the activity stack while launching the next one

Tags: android

In my application there is a login page.which is the first activity.after sucessfully entering through the login page.i dont want to see the login page after the first use.but every time the application is opening i need the login page.thats why i am not using the shared preferrence.please help me.

```
etuserid = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etuserid);
        etpass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etlogpassword);
        login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btlogin);
        namevaluepair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                userid = etuserid.getText().toString();
                pass = etpass.getText().toString();

                String url = "http://mytesting.hostingsiteforfree.com/POS/login.php";
                new LoginTask().execute(url, userid, pass);

            }
        });
      //  finish();
    }
```

Comment: Try to call "finish()" into onPOstExecute of your LoginTask, where you are moving into next activity

Comment: activities are pushed in Stack manner so an activity pushed first cannot be removed first I guess, use preferences once logged in or override onBackPressed() on your second activity to skip the login activity ..

Comment: It can be removed. Try to call Activity B from Activity A, where A - first activity in app and call finish() in next line after startActivity() - it will work.

Comment: thanks @ Dimmerg it worked for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is similar to a "splash screen" in behavior then. To achieve that, you need to call `finish()` (which you have commented out) just after starting the next activity. Why did you comment that out, not doing what you want?

```
// Start your app main activity
Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(i);

// close this activity
finish();
```

http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/how-to-implement-android-splash-screen-2/

Answer (score 1):

Write this when you're starting new activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);     
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: i wrriten this in my first activity.but when back key pressed  login page reappeared before exiting the application.

Answer (score 0):

You can clear the stack or even the particular task using the setFlags() method.

To know more about the different flags that you can pass to the setFlags() method, go through [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK) link!!!